# conditional formatting to highlight cells based on cell value of same cell of different sheet

Tags: vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I have sheet 1 as data. Sheet 2 as 'Adjustments'. The formula in sheet2!a1 is `=sheet1!a1`. This is throughout all cells in sheet2. The idea is that a user can make an adjustment in sheet2 by adding to result/zeroising/blanking the formula without touching source data. I want these cells highlighted to show that this value is a adjustment and not equal to its corresponding cell in sheet1. eg for cell l15

```
With Range("L15").FormatConditions.Add( _
        Type:=xlExpression, _
        Formula1:="=L15<>'sheet1'!L15")
            .Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
        .Font.Color = RGB(0, 97, 0)
 End With
```

is what I have used. I want to apply that to every cell in sheet 2 that is not equal to its precedent cell in sheet1. T
hanks

Comment: Use the sheets change event to do this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx

Comment: thanks Nathan. this is way simpler than what I was attempting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the sheets change event to do this msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx